# Supports of np.digitize

Tags: cupy

I see the cupy version of np.digitize is not yet supported. Are there plans to make this function work in cupy?
If not, is there an easy solution to implement the functionality for cupy arrays?

Comment: The work is in progress here: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/2726

Comment: Great, thank you for the quick comment, going to follow up with the development.